# How to spoof NMEA sentences on physical Android 8.1 phone for apps like WeChat?

Tags: gps, geolocation, magisk, xposed-framework, edxposed

**The problem.** Location spoofing is fairly simple for most Android apps. It's done either by using Xposed modules such as XPricyLua or by using a location spoofing app such as [Fake GPS Location](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps&hl=en&gl=US) or even both. But few sophisticated apps such as [WeChat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tencent.mm&hl=en&gl=US) or [GPS Info & NMEA Logging](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lrbgames.gps_info_logging&hl=en&gl=US) will anyway detect your real location even if you use an Xposed module or a FakeGPS app or even both. It happens because they utilize hardware level SDK (e.g. BaiduLocationSDK) and will relay on NMEA sentences rather than LocationManager and FusedLocationProvider APIs. There's a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37175039/how-does-some-appswechat-ignore-fake-location-and-then-detect-the-real-one) on stackoverflow that haven't been resolved.

**Spoofing methods I have tried and they haven't worked** (even on rooted Android):

- Xposed Modules such as XPrivacyLua and LocationInjector (apps see NMEA sentences from real location)
- Anything using Developer options, mock location app ([Fake GPS location](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps&hl=en&gl=US), MockGeoFix, Bluetooth GPS Provider)
- Fused location provider spoofing with apps using both mock location and Xposed module ([Mock Locations (fake GPS path)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.gavrikov.mocklocations&hl=en&gl=US))
- IP geolocation spoofing (VPN)
- GPS provider spoofing & IP geolocation spoofing
- geo nmea and geo fix commands (worked on emulator, MockGeoFix doesn't show NMEA sentences)

**Ideas.** Some GPS-over-bluetooth/network/serial apps such as [GNSSTool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.huace.gnssserver&hl=en&gl=US) or [GPS Connector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.pilablu.gpsconnector&hl=en&gl=US) almost do the work. They are able to receive NMEA sentences from other hardware devices (e.g. Android phone) or even replay them from nmea-files BUT but WeChat and GPS Info & NMEA Logging doesn't see satellites and NMEA sentences anyway (as mock location app selected).

**The question.** Are there any other applications, modules (Xposed, Magisk), methods or ideas to spoof location in apps relaying on NMEA sentences on a physical Android 8.1 phone?

Comment: It seems to be possible by kernel modification, see post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382931/android-emulate-gps-satellites-not-only-location

Comment: HackRF is proven hardware solution at about $300: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-bdK7tRpBI